# Open data high resolution satellite images

Tags: uses-of-open-data, images, remote-sensing

I recently learned that there are satellite images with a resolution of 30 centimeters, coming from sensors launched on WorldView-3 and 4, and I think there are others as well. My question is whether these images are also available for free or not.

I don't know if there are other satellite systems with high resolution available for free. Are there?